# My merge sort program is not working if the elements in the array are greater than 16

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

Here is the code.
If any element in the array becomes greater than 16 then it just produces the wrong output.
Looking for someone's help to point out my mistake.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r){
    int n1=q-p+1; // length of first subarray
    int n2=r-q; // length of second subarray
    int L[n1+1], R[n2+1]; // Size is taken n+1 to store sentinal at last
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
        L[i]=A[p+i];
    }
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
        R[j]=A[q+j+1];
    }

    L[n1+1]=-1; // '-1' is a sentinal
    R[n2+1]=-1;
    i=0,j=0;
    for(k=p;k<r+1;k++){
        if(L[i]<=R[j]){
            A[k]=L[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else{
            A[k]=R[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int p, int r){
    int q;
    if(p<r){
        q=(p+r)/2;
        mergeSort(arr,p,q);
        mergeSort(arr,q+1,r);
        merge(arr,p,q,r);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n=8;
    int arr[n]={7,2,1,3,5,6,2,4}; // Not working for arr[i]>16
    mergeSort(arr,0,n-1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Please review my code and help me find the problem!

Comment: Your program uses [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and those [are not part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I also recommend you take this opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend you use semantically relevant variable names rather than short one or two letter names, to make the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: Please provide the expected and actual output from your example code. (Demonstrating the functional failure might require changing your initial values since none of them are greater than 16.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But I can't exactly get why I need to use vector for this program. It doesn't seem to be a vector problem. Also, if it is, can you brief me a little bit as why a variable length array. And yeah, thanks for your debugger suggestion, I'll surely start learning it.

Comment: You use features that aren't standard C++. Variable-length arrays are typically taught on so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites, and such sites are *not* learning or teaching resources and should never be used as such! If you really want to learn programming and C++ properly, invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take classes.

Comment: Also don't forget the zero-based array indexes for arrays and vectors. If you have an array of `n1 + 1` elements, then the index `n1 + 1` will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*.